# Speed control in 100Hz to 10KHz range reading small records from file on windows

Tags: c++, windows, performance

I have developed a complex program for a client on windows desktop.  I am required to control the speed reading multiple small records ( ~20bytes ) in sequence from two large files.  Running on my systems I can get reasonable control in the range 10 to 1000Hz  The client reports that when he runs on his systems that he can only get  a maximum about 100 reads per second.

The speed control does not need to be very precise, just 20% might be acceptable, but it should be consistent - increasing the speed setting should increase the speed in the expected proportion.

I have implemented the reads using the C++ library ( ifstream ) and the windows API ( CreateFile, with the prefetch cache optimized for sequential access ).  The performance is similar.

The client has turned off his virus protection, windows search indexing and all other running applications with no significant change

**Update:**

I have discovered that the problem is not with the disk reads themselves, but with the code that throttles down the maximum read speed to the required rate.  If I disable this code and let the reads run free, the client machines are capable of almost 50,000 reads per second.  ( This is too fast for the rest of the application to keep up, so it must be throttled back )  So the problem is with the sub millisecond timers used to throttle back the read speed to something the application can handle.  On my machines I can get sub millisecond delays, but the same code on the client machine will only allow a delay of a millisecond or more.

To demonstrate the problem and satisfy the folks who insist on seeing some code, here is a greatly simplified test showing the problem when the timer is not capable of delivering short delays.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include "cRunCount.h"

using namespace std;

/** Length of timed wait */
int WaitMicroSecs;

boost::asio::deadline_timer  * myPlaybackTimer;

/** Frequency counter from https://github.com/JamesBremner/raven-set
 Construct to report after 500 calls
*/
raven::set::cRunCount        myRunCounter( 500 );

void StartWait();

/** Called when timer expires

In production code this would start the next read
but for this test it simply restarts the timer

*/
void handle_expire(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/)
{

    if( myRunCounter.Count() )
    {
        // The run counter has been called 500 times, output report
        cout << WaitMicroSecs << " microsecs ( nominal "
        << 1000000 / WaitMicroSecs << " Hz ) -> "
        << myRunCounter.Hz() << " Hz\n";

        // check if test complete
        if( WaitMicroSecs == 1 )
            exit(0);

        // next test nominally ten times faster
        WaitMicroSecs /= 10;
    }

    // start next timed wait
    StartWait();
}

/** Called to start a new timed wait */
void StartWait()
{
    myPlaybackTimer->expires_from_now(
                      boost::posix_time::microseconds( WaitMicroSecs ) );
    myPlaybackTimer->async_wait( handle_expire );

}

int main( int argc, char * argv[])
{

    WaitMicroSecs = 100000;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    myPlaybackTimer = new boost::asio::deadline_timer( io_service );

    // Start first wait
    StartWait();

    // start event loop
    io_service.run();

    return 0;
}
```

The output from this is:

```
100000 microsecs ( nominal 10 Hz ) -> 9.17304 Hz
10000 microsecs ( nominal 100 Hz ) -> 64.2066 Hz
1000 microsecs ( nominal 1000 Hz ) -> 65.4417 Hz
100 microsecs ( nominal 10000 Hz ) -> 78.407 Hz
10 microsecs ( nominal 100000 Hz ) -> 75.6637 Hz
1 microsecs ( nominal 1000000 Hz ) -> 69.206 Hz
```

Notice how the the frequency is fine with a 100 millisecond delay, and almost OK with a 10 millisecond delay but anything shorter does not in fact deliver the nominal frequency - is in fact no quicker

In the production code, I use the high performance counter which delivers better results on my machine.  Here are the results for this

```
100000 microsecs ( nominal 10 Hz ) -> 9.29206 Hz
10000 microsecs ( nominal 100 Hz ) -> 81.1589 Hz
1000 microsecs ( nominal 1000 Hz ) -> 733.746 Hz
100 microsecs ( nominal 10000 Hz ) -> 345.407 Hz
10 microsecs ( nominal 100000 Hz ) -> 126.579 Hz
1 microsecs ( nominal 1000000 Hz ) -> 1994.5 Hz
```

Here the delay seems fairly reasonable down to 1 millisecond, but anything shorted becomes erratic.

Similar results are obtained on the client's machines, which solves the original problem!

**Update:**

Following a suggestion from Hans Passant I have concluded that the clock interrupt rate must be low on the client's machines.  I have added a call to  [timeBeginPeriod()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx) to ensure that it runs at the fastest possible speed, 1 millisecond.  Still waiting for test report from the client.

I have concluded that since the interrupt clock will not run faster than 1 millisecond, frequencies in the 1 to 10KHz range will not be possible using a timer. So I have developed a busy loop timer running in its own thread to serve the purpose.  This seems to work well, despite the extravagant use of CPU cycles.  The test program code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/high_resolution_timer.hpp>

#include "cRunCount.h"

using namespace std;

/** Length of timed wait */
int WaitMicroSecs;

/** Target frequency */
int TargetHz;

/** The event loop */
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

/** Timer used when wait is more than 1 millisecond */
boost::asio::high_resolution_timer  * myPlaybackTimer;

/** Thread where busy loop timer runs */
std::thread * BusyLoopThread;

/** Frequency counter from https://github.com/JamesBremner/raven-set
 Construct to report after 2000 calls
*/
raven::set::cRunCount        myRunCounter( 2000 );

/** Function forward declerations */
void StartWait();
void handle_expire(const boost::system::error_code& );

/** Flag used by busy loop timer to indicate completion */
bool BusyLoopTimerDone;

/** protection against data races on busy loop completion flag */
std::mutex M;

/** The Busy Loop timer, runs in own thread */
void BusyLoopTimer()
{
    __int64 myTimeStart, t, myFreq;
    float MicroSecs;
    QueryPerformanceCounter( (LARGE_INTEGER *)&myTimeStart );
    QueryPerformanceFrequency( (LARGE_INTEGER *)&myFreq );
    do
    {
        int loopCount = 200;

        // the busy loop
        while( loopCount > 0 )
            loopCount--;
        QueryPerformanceCounter( (LARGE_INTEGER *)&t );
        MicroSecs = 1000000.0 * (float)(t-myTimeStart) / (float)myFreq;
    }
    // keep on going until specified wait has been reached
    while( MicroSecs < WaitMicroSecs );

    // flag completion
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock( M );
    BusyLoopTimerDone = true;

    // the thread now completes
}

void CheckBusyLoopDone()
{
    // read completion flag
    bool done;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock( M );
        done = BusyLoopTimerDone;
    }
    if( ! done )
    {
        // still running
        // post the next check
        // in a real application, this would allow other processing
        // to execute in this thread
        io_service.post( CheckBusyLoopDone );
    }
    else
    {
        // busy loop timer completed
        // execute completion handler
        handle_expire( boost::system::error_code() );
    }
}

/** Set up for next tests */
void NextTestDelay()
{
    // check if test is over
    if( TargetHz >= 5000 )
    {
        cout << "Test completed\n";
        io_service.stop();
    }

    // target frequency for next tests
    TargetHz += 1000;

    // fudge factor
    const int overheadmsecs = 120;

    // Calculate microseconds wait required
    WaitMicroSecs = 1000000 / TargetHz - overheadmsecs;

}

/** Called when timer expires

In production code this would start the next read
but for this test it simply restarts the timer

*/
void handle_expire(const boost::system::error_code& /*e*/)
{
// Do some thread cleanup
// this does not seem to be neccessary
// since the thread finishes when it completes anyway
// and it adds a noticeable overhead
//    BusyLoopThread->join();
//    delete BusyLoopThread;

    if( myRunCounter.Count() )
    {
        // The run counter has been called reuired times, output report
        cout << "Target " << TargetHz << " Hz Actual: "
    //            << WaitMicroSecs << " microsecs ( nominal "
    //         << 1000000 / WaitMicroSecs << " Hz ) -> "
             << (int)myRunCounter.Hz() << " Hz, delta "
             << (int)(myRunCounter.Hz() - TargetHz) << "\n";

        // check if test complete
        NextTestDelay();
    }

    // start next timed wait
    StartWait();
}

/** Called to start a new timed wait */
void StartWait()
{
    if( WaitMicroSecs > 1000 )
    {
        // use high performance timer
        // which should be reliable for waits longer than a millisecond

        myPlaybackTimer->expires_from_now(
            std::chrono::microseconds( WaitMicroSecs ) );
        myPlaybackTimer->async_wait( handle_expire );
    }
    else
    {
        // too fast for clock interupt timer
        // so start busy loop timer in its own thread
        BusyLoopTimerDone = false;
        BusyLoopThread = new std::thread( BusyLoopTimer );
        io_service.post( CheckBusyLoopDone );
    }

}

int main( int argc, char * argv[])
{
    cout << "Busy Loop timer\n";

    // ensure that the interrupt clock rate is at its maximum
    // 1 millisecond
    MMRESULT  res = timeBeginPeriod( 1 );
    if( res != TIMERR_NOERROR )
    {
        cout << "timeBeginPeriod no can do\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    TargetHz = 0;
    NextTestDelay();

    myPlaybackTimer = new boost::asio::high_resolution_timer( io_service );

    // Start first wait
    StartWait();

    // start event loop
    io_service.run();

    return 0;
}
```

Results

```
Busy Loop timer
Target 1000 Hz Actual: 987 Hz, delta -12
Target 2000 Hz Actual: 1983 Hz, delta -16
Target 3000 Hz Actual: 2976 Hz, delta -23
Target 4000 Hz Actual: 4086 Hz, delta 86
Target 5000 Hz Actual: 4919 Hz, delta -80
Test completed
```

This has been tested at the client's site and gives similar results.

**Continuous Busy Loop Timer**

The above code requires a new thread to be created for each wait time request.  Since my application does many tens of thousands of wait time requests, I am concerned about the impact on the main processing thread.  So I have developed a continuous busy loop timer - this runs continuously and services wait time requests one at a time.  This appears to work well, but the calibration overhead allowance is more complex for reasons I do not know, which is a bit of a concern.  [The test code is here](https://gist.github.com/JamesBremner/d296f089dc6097021d693345e60d1349).

Comment: Start with a [mcve].  Without a repro case, nobody here can do any better than speculation and unfounded guesswork.

Comment: @ravenspoint: First *chill out*. When asking for help you get better results from being courteous to people giving advice (whether you actually decide to follow their advice or not). Second, what do you expect from StackOverflow? If you want people to spot a problem in your code, the first thing is to give them the code. Without code, as Ryan mentioned, there is no diagnosis possible, only wild guesses, and that is a waste of both our and your time. Did you consider that maybe, with your code, some people will actually be able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Timers can only tick at the clock interrupt rate on Windows.  By default it ticks 64 times per second, 15.625 msec.  Running a browser tends to increase the rate to 10 msec, the happy GIF number.  Underlying winapi call is timeBeginPeriod(), goes as low as 1 msec.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for timeBeginPeriod().  This looks to be very useful for removing the dependency on other programs running.

Comment: Would a call to give up the remaining time slice on the busy thread be appropriate each time the inner loop exits? This would reduce burning of CPU cycles when there is something else to do. Not sure as to the effect on your timing though.

Comment: @RichardChambers I do not immediately see the potential benefit of your suggestion.  Can you explain?  How long would a timeslice typically be?  As I understand it, the timeslice only applies when context switches occur - in this case the busy loop thread runs continuously in its own logical processor

Comment: In a multi-threading OS threads appear as a kind of light weight process. Time slice allocation by the OS is at the thread level. OS assigns threads to CPU cores allowing threads to run for some duration before being halted at the end of their assigned time period in order to allow another thread to start running. A running thread can give up its time through an OS call for I/O or other actions. With busy wait thread will run until its time slice expires blocking any other waiting thread from using that core unless interrupted. If this causes problems, busy wait with reschedule may help.

Comment: "in order to allow another thread to start running" As I mentioned, I am devoting a logical processor to the busy loop thread since I cannot afford the time to do a context switch.  In general, a high performance application cannot afford to run more threads than there are logical processors because you end up devoting more CPU cycles to context switching than to processing!

Comment: @HansPassant I have now received a test report from the client, showing that the call to  timeBeginPeriod() solves the original problem of the client running much slower on his machines.  Thanks again.  Post you comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: I completely did not understand what you were trying to achieve, rather best if you complete this Q+A yourself.  Mark your post as the answer to close the question.

Comment: @HansPassant Whether you completely understood or not, your comment nailed the solution!

Answer (score 0):

first: do a benchmark program for reading chunk from a file at diffrent sizes. See what size offers the best performance.

Find a way to read this into memory and assign the info to objects. You could try to somehow map your objects over the memory directly. Maeby placement new could help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.  Modern disk drives and operating systems use a pre-fetch cache so that no matter how small a record the application code reads, the actual physical read from the disk surface is optimal.  So, changing the record size requested by the application code has very little impact on the read performance.  This is why I suspected the client had disable prefetch - but see the update to my question.

Comment: Wouldn't a ring buffer between your reading thread and the rest of the app solve the problem? Just stop the reading thread when the buffer is full and start it again when it is free over a certain level? (consummer-producer problem) This might be more complex than I imagine right now because of interfaces in your up but maybe you find a way startig with this ideea.

Comment: Thanks for your further suggestion.  My original question post was confusing because I did not fully understand where my problem lay.  I have edited it so that now it should be clearer.  Your buffer suggestion does not help, because I would still have the problem of reading from the buffer at the required speed.